# Asus Vivobook X512 SSD (new)

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, asus, raid

This laptop has a 512GB SSD drive (using memory sticks);  the laptop works perfectly with Ubuntu 18.4 from a live usb drive;  the goal was to dual boot though Ubuntu only would be fine as well

However the laptop has INTEL OPTANE RST RAID driver memory set in the BIOS (which means the disks show up as /dev/nvme* drives not /dev/sd*).  The Ubuntu installer will not install to a nvme* type drive (likely as the Optane is interfering with the drive management and Optane is only for windows);  Ubuntu appears to only install to AHCI type drivers;

from what I can read from others one has to shut off OPTANE management at the windows level then move from OPTANE to AHCI at the BIOS level;  then install Ubuntu like normal; then reengage the OPTANE at the BIOS and reengage the OPTANE at the windows level

Unfortunately there is no AHCI option in the BIOS although there is a DISABLE option for the OPTANE memory.

The BIOS is American Megatrends APTIO

So the questions:

Does anyone have experience with this setup where there is no definitive AHCI option and successfully dual booting?

Does disable of Optane Driver mean AHCI by default?

Perhaps disabling Optane means we could run Ubuntu ONLY and use the whole SSD drive for Ubuntu?

I have had 40 years experience with *nix.

Update 1:  have tried Ubuntu Mate 20.04;  install went through installing linux to the free space allocated but it did not place Grub alongside Windows Manager;  so it is likely Optane in preventing writing to that part of the disk

Update 2:  in Bios have disabled fastboot, secure boot, and Optane and
have set disk type to AHCI (instead of raid)

have tried installing a number of ways (including added nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency=5500 to the ubiquity line) and continue to get [errno 5] input/output failure when the installer attempts to write to the drive

Comment: Here lies your anser - Does disable of Optane Driver mean AHCI by default? try this one and report back.